# Multiple boolean functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, boolean

I got these 2 boolean functions:

```
 def settled?
    self.settled == true
 end

 def negative_pl?
    self.profitloss < 0
 end
```

How can I test for both of them at the same time? I want to do something like this in my view:

```
<%= 'classRed' if bet.settled?.negative_pl? %>
```

I know the above don't work, but the best way to explain what I want to do :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= 'classRed' if bet.settled? and bet.negative_pl? %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a clause per check:

```
if bet.settled? and bet.negative_pl?
```